# tcl entry with some default text

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want an entry widget with some default text shown in the box. -state disable. When I click on edit button, it will be enable and I can able to change the text. I can manage the Edit button portion, just need help about the entry widget.

I have tried with this code :

```
entry .e1 -text "abcd" -state disable
pack .e1 -in .WorkArea -side left
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frame .workArea
pack .workArea
```

Note that the `-text` option is an abbreviation of `-textvariable`, i.e. the name of a global variable that contains the text entered into the entry widget. Setting that variable to a value gives the entry some text.

```
entry .e1 -textvariable abcd -state disabled
set abcd wxyz
pack .e1 -in .workArea -side left
```

You now need a button that configures the entry widget to be normal (enabled) when it is pushed:

```
button .b1 -text Enable -command {.e1 configure -state normal}
pack .b1 -in .workArea -side left
```

Documentation:
[button (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/button.htm),
[entry](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/entry.htm),
[frame (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/frame.htm),
[pack](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)